# A good HTML-embedded code highlighter for JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What is a good Code Highlighter / Editor for JavaScript/jQuery. It is needed *embedded in* a website and should be style-able and, lightweight.

Comment: try firerainbow , it shows in firebug http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/10-useful-firefox-extensions-to-supercharge-firebug/

Comment: Can anyone tell which highlighter this page uses " http://www.zurb.com/playground/css-boxshadow-experiments "

Comment: @neeraj , you need to write parsers for that.

Comment: Non-Jquery but Javascript, anyone ?

Comment: It sounds like you want a rich HTML/JS (code) editor. What language(s) do you want it to support? Just JavaScript or are you looking for just a good *(rich) text editor*?

Comment: yes | as much as it can, no language boundations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Google's [prettifyer](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for syntax highlightning.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is pretty great. It doesn't try to autocomplete your code, and it has syntax highlighting for a bunch of languages including JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: There are also online editors. I thought i could get a better one here. That's all

Answer (score 0):

If you have money this is really nice.. try the trailversion

```
http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/
```

Answer (score 0):

Komodo Edit on OSX (free)